# Yellowish tint on screen in Windows 11 laptop

Tags: laptop, display, windows-11, amd-radeon, hp

I have a hp 15s Ryzen 3 5300U laptop with AMD radeon graphics. I bought the laptop yesterday and since then I have a yellowish tint on the screen. The night mode is off, so it's not because of that. I have tried updating the graphics driver but it is already updated to the latest version.

Kindly help me in resolving the issue. I have tried googling and following their solutions but in vain.

Comment: If you bought the laptop yesterday it is still under warranty, right? Did you buy it from a shop?

Comment: @Gantendo Yes. Before I bought the laptop I read about its reviews online and few customers had the same problem when they purchased it. Some of them fixed their issue by calibrating the color display. I seem to have some problem concerning this calibration.

Comment: …so your question becomes, "how do I calibrate it?"

Comment: I think we need a bit more info. Do you know how to calibrate it? What happens if you try to calibrate it? Any error messages or a detailed problem description would be nice. Which things have you googled? What happened when you tried them? Are you using the latest drivers? E.g. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Yellowish-Screen/td-p/6807153

Comment: @Gantendo I know how to calibrate it. I tried it but I am unable to set the RGB settings to a perfect match synchronously. I have already looked at the link and done the same but in vain

Comment: @Tetsujin if it will solve my problem then yes

Comment: If you can't do it by eye, then you need a hardware colorimeter - or just send the laptop back.